# Pandas - Use groupby and filter on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a dataset by IDs, then by time. Then, I want to select records based on the criteria of one column and based on time by ID.

I have been researching and playing around for hours now, but I have no luck.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2','A3','A3', 'A4', 'A3', 'A2', "A4", "A4", "A4"],
                   'value': ["7:00","10:00","20:00","9:00","7:00","9:00","8:00","15:00","19:00", "9:30", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30"],
                   "value2": [3,1,2,4,2,3,3,5,3,2,1,5,7],
                   'value3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange","Apple"],
                  "value4": ["Throw", "Eat", 'Throw', "Keep", "Eat", "Eat", "Throw", "Throw", "Throw", "Throw", "Eat", "Eat", "Chuck"]})

df["value"] = pd.to_datetime(df["value"])
```

Updated:

What I want is: 1) By ID (variable "a"), select all instances under "value3" where it is "orange" and then "apple". They don't have to be back to back; there can be many other values between these two. But orange must come before apple in time.

2) Then count these instances, but:

3) Under "value 2", you will notice that sometimes there is a "1" associated with an "orange". There are two groups that I want to calculate this pattern of "orange then apple": 1) one is when value2 is = 1 for orange; the other is when orange does not equal 1 (so the rest are grouped as one group).

Comment: Is this typo should it be A3 not A4 ?

Answer (score 0):

We need `groupby` + `shift` ,

```
df.loc[(df.groupby(["a"]).value2.shift()+df.value2).eq('OrangeApple'),'a']
Out[287]: 
2    A1
6    A3
9    A2
Name: a, dtype: object


df.loc[(df.groupby(["a"]).value2.shift()+df.value2).eq('OrangeApple'),'a'].nunique()
Out[288]: 3
```

Comment: I updated my code probably when you responded. But this isn't what I am looking for. A1 should evaluated to true; A2 should evaluate to true; A3 should evaluate to true; A4 should evaluate to false.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I looked at the dataset again, and there is an added complexity (I updated my code above). I do apologize that this is a silly example, but I can't post my actual dataset. Your code works well, except for A4 now. A4 will be essentially double counted if I try to filter the two groups. In this case, A4 should be positive for value2 = 1, but false for the value2 = 5 right after. I hope this make sense.