# Pandas - Groupby find groups within groups

Tags: python, pandas

This is a repost from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211796/pandas-use-groupby-and-filter-on-multiple-conditions) I started, but I have realized the problem is much more complex.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2','A3','A3', 'A4', 'A3', 'A2', "A4", "A4", "A4"],
                   'value': ["7:00","10:00","20:00","9:00","7:00","9:00","8:00","15:00","19:00", "9:30", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30"],
                   "value2": [3,1,2,4,2,3,3,5,3,2,1,5,7],
                   'value3': ["Apple", "Orange", "Apple", "Kiwi", "Orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange","Apple"],
                  "value4": ["Throw", "Eat", 'Throw', "Keep", "Eat", "Eat", "Throw", "Throw", "Throw", "Throw", "Eat", "Eat", "Chuck"]})
```

What I want is: 1) By ID (variable "a"), select all instances under "value3" where it is "orange" and then "apple". They don't have to be back to back; there can be many other values between these two. But orange must come before apple in time.

2) Then count these instances of orange then apple into two groups: 1) one is when value2 is = 1 for orange; 2) is when orange does not equal 1 (so the rest are grouped as one group).
The problem is A4 where there is two oranges - 1 and 5. This should be categorized in the group value2 = 1 because it happened first in time.

Update: Sorry - my expected response did not cut and paste over it seems:

```
value2     value3     count
1          orange     2
all other  orange     2
```

Comment: can you post the expected result?

Comment: My apologies - it didn't copy over from my workspace for whatever reason. Please see updated response.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works, however I will see if some others can give you a simple and short version of it,

```
    df1 = df[['a','value3']].drop_duplicates()
##Merging the dataframes
merge =df1.merge(df,how = 'left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
##Selecting the only requried columns
merge = merge[['value2','value3_x']]
##Renaming the columns
merge = merge.rename(columns={'value3_x':'value3'})
##Filtering the data
merge = merge[merge.value3=='Orange']
##Converting te value to string
merge['value2']= df.value2.astype(str) 
## Changing the value of value2
merge['value2'] = merge.value2.apply(lambda x: '1' if x == '1' else 'all other')
##Grouping the data
merge.groupby(['value2','value3']).value3.count()
```